# Query Postgres JSONB where key doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Given a set of data.

```
1 | { 'completed': true }
2 | { 'office_completed': false }
```

Is there a way to query `office_completed != 'true'` and have it return both records? Or a way to select all records that DON'T have the `office_completed` key? I can query all records which have the `office_completed` key with:

`SELECT * FROM jsonb WHERE data ? 'office_completed';`

But couldn't find a way to pull the opposite.

What brings me to this problem is that I have a data set that may or may not have the `office_completed` key and I need to query all records that have `office_completed != 'true'` but if the key doesn't exist I get nothing from it. If the key doesn't exist, I'd think that would count as `!=true` but it apparently doesn't. :-) I figured the alternative would be to select all records that don't have the `office_completed` key OR `office_completed != 'true'` but can't figure out how to do that.

I appreciate it if somebody has a better idea for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just for reference for previous post.

Simply using NOT() like that if want to find all record don't have key:

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb WHERE NOT( data ? 'office_completed' );
```

Comment: This should be an approved answer. Smart way to alter a jsonb operator.

Multiple keys that exist in jsonb_column:

```SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE jsonb_column ?| '{ "filter", "existed" }'::text[]```

Multiple keys that not exist in jsonb_column:

```SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE NOT( jsonb_column ?| '{ "filter", "not", "existed" }'::text[])```

Answer (score 12):

Use [coalesce()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

```
select *
from jsonb
where coalesce(data->>'office_completed', 'false') <> 'true';

 id |            data             
----+-----------------------------
  1 | {"completed": true}
  2 | {"office_completed": false}
(2 rows)
```

See how it works:

```
select *, data->>'office_completed' as value, coalesce(data->>'office_completed', 'false')
from jsonb
where coalesce(data->>'office_completed', 'false') <> 'true';

 id |            data             | value | coalesce 
----+-----------------------------+-------+----------
  1 | {"completed": true}         |       | false
  2 | {"office_completed": false} | false | false
(2 rows)
```